# How to modify navigation menu in main.cs while using WindowsTemplateStudio?

Tags: uwp, windows-template-studio

I'm using `WindowsTemplateStudio`, For some reason, I have to modify navigation menu in `MainPage.xaml.cs`, like remove or add some items.
How to do? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created a `Navigation Pane` via **WindowsTemplateStudio**, you can find the `NavigationView` in `Views/ShellPage.xaml` where you can add a `NavigationViewItem`.

In the `NavigationViewItem`, `x:Uid` points to the text resource in `Strings/en-us`.

If necessary, you can also add shortcuts in ShellPage.xaml.cs.

---

**Update**

If you want to modify the `NavigationView` in the ShellPage on other pages, you need to do some extra work.

1. Set the NavigationView's `x:FieldModifier` property to `Public`

```xml
<winui:NavigationView
    x:Name="navigationView"
    x:FieldModifier="Public"
    ...>
</winui:NavigationView>
```

2. Create a static instance of `ShellPage`

```cs
public static ShellPage Current;

public ShellPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    Current = this;
    Initialize();
}
```

3. Complete the operation of NavigationView through `ShellPage.Current.navigationView`

```cs
foreach (var item in ShellPage.Current.navigationView.MenuItems)
{
    var navItem = item as NavigationViewItem;
    // Todo
}
```

Of course, this way can directly achieve the goal. But in comparison, I prefer to use Binding, generate MenuItems by creating `ObservableCollection<T>` and bind to `navigationView.MenuItemsSource`.

Best regards.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to add items in ShellPage.xaml. Now in MainPage.xaml.cs, how to to. Thx.